# numpy pass partly defined filename to genfromtxt

Tags: python, numpy

I have data files which I know the beginning and the end of their name. the names are structured as :
###_random_string.EXT
where ### is a number from 000 to 999 and EXT the files extension (here csv). The number of files could be big, this is the reason why I'm using a python code to process them (smoothing, filtering, plotting, ...).
The code in which these files will be processed will use numpy.genfromtxt to load the data of each file. I will put numpy.genfromtxt in a loop passing through a list of numbers (FilesNum) corresponding to the files to be processed. I would like to construct the filename with only ### given by 'FilesNum' and the extension. Here is a start :

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import re

FilesNum = range(0, 350, 2)
EXT = 'csv'
X, Y = [], []
for num in FilesNum:
    data = np.genfromtxt(glob.glob(str(num) + '*' + EXT), delimiter = ';')
    X.append(data[:, 0])
    Y.append(data[:, 1])
```

My problem here is that glob.glob(FilesNum + '*' + EXT) does not what I need as it should generate a list. In my specific case for each number corresponds only one file. Taking into account this point I need a code that will replace '*' by the exact missing part of the file name.

If the file starting with 0 is '000_random_string.csv' :

```
np.genfromtxt(glob.glob('000_' + '*' + '.csv'), delimiter = ',')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-fefca52f40e1> in <module>()
----> 1 np.genfromtxt(glob.glob('%03d' % 0 + '*' + '.csv'), delimiter = ',')

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.pyc in genfromtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, skiprows, skip_header, skip_footer, converters, missing, missing_values, filling_values, usecols, names, excludelist, deletechars, replace_space, autostrip, case_sensitive, defaultfmt, unpack, usemask, loose, invalid_raise)
   1294     # Skip the first `skip_header` rows
   1295     for i in xrange(skip_header):
-> 1296         fhd.next()
   1297 
   1298     # Keep on until we find the first valid values

StopIteration:
```

While :

```
np.genfromtxt('000_random_string.csv', delimiter = ',')
Out[30]: 
array([[  350.   ,  -210.   ],
       [  351.4  ,  -210.   ],
       [  352.8  ,   -42.608],
       ..., 
       [ 1747.2  ,   -62.798],
       [ 1748.6  ,  -210.   ],
       [ 1750.   ,  -210.   ]])
```

note that :

```
glob.glob('%03d' % 0 + '*' + '.csv')
Out[31]: ['000_random_string.csv']
```

Comment: I think you might have made a mistake in putting "FilesNum" inside for you for loop where you should have taken num (because that is what you are actually looping over..)
so your line 8 should read: data = np.genfromtxt(glob.glob(num + '*' + EXT), delimiter = ';')

Comment: have you tried what the result of glob.glob(0 + "\*" + EXT) would give you? this would be your first iteration. It would also be helpful if you could post some example filenames in you question, this would make it easier to see why you glob fails. One thing that strikes me is that you add the variable num which is an int to a string. This does not work in my python interpereter, so maybe glob.glob( str(num) + '*' + EXT) will bring you closer to your answer.

Comment: yes, it's a mistake; I just corrected by adding str() to num. If file starting with number 0 is "000_random_string.csv", then glob.glob('%03d' % 0 + '\*' + '.csv') yields ['000_random_string.csv'].

Comment: I re-edited as the example file name on the second line was not appearing properly. I had to prepend a backslash to '###'.

Answer (score 1):

ok, I found my solution. I only needed to give an index to glob.glob(). As I said for each number exists only one file, so giving index 0 will always do what I want here.

```
np.genfromtxt(glob.glob('000_' + '*' + '.csv')[0], delimiter = ',')
                                               ^
                                               |-- the solution
Out[5]: 
array([[  350.   ,  -210.   ],
       [  351.4  ,  -210.   ],
       [  352.8  ,   -42.608],
       ..., 
       [ 1747.2  ,   -62.798],
       [ 1748.6  ,  -210.   ],
       [ 1750.   ,  -210.   ]])
```

Comment: Oh, now I see. yes indeed, glob returns a list. But genfromtxt also accepts a string or an iterator and I thought you were trying to use the iterator. but them Martin is actually right, you don't really need glob, if the "random_string" does not change with the files.

Comment: Who said "random_string" does not change with the files?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing path to the directory of the files.

Furthermore, it is unnecessary to call glob.glob on the filename.

```
f_name = '.'.join([str(num), ext])
```

should do it. It converts the file_number into string and concatenates it with the file extension (the separator is the dot).

Then the complete path to file is:

```
import os
f_path = os.path.join(dir_path, f_name)
```

Edit: Thanks for the comment. I should have googled first, now I get the question (probably). Will leave it as it is.

Comment: well the glob is necessary if you want to get all kinds of "random_strings"

Comment: That's right. I didn't understand the question correctly at first because the ### was missing at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think we are close to a solution here:

I think if you use the tip with the %-formating that Martin supplied you are there (however if I undersood you correctly you still need the glob if the random_strings are different).
so your files are 0000_randomstring1.csv, 0000_randomstring2.csv ... 0000_randomstringN.csv, 0002_randomstring1.csv, 0002_randomstring2.csv ... 0000_randomstringN.csv ... 0350_randomstringN.csv, right? and you want the ones with the same number to be read as if they were one file, right?

then this hould work:

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import re

FilesNum = range(0, 350, 2)
EXT = 'csv'
X, Y = [], []
for num in FilesNum:
    data = np.genfromtxt(glob.glob( "%04d*%s"%( num, EXT ) ), delimiter = ';').T
    X.append( data[0] )
    Y.append( data[1] )
```

if you want just all files to be read into one large file you could just as well do

```
AllFilesAsList = glob.glob( "0*.csv" )
X,Y = np.genfromtxt(AllFilesAsList, delimiter = ';').T
```

Oh, now I get it:

so what I'd recommend you doing is then

```
Files = [ glob.glob( "%04d*%s"%( num, EXT ) for num in range(0,350,2) )]
```

now you can actually look at all the files it finds and your loop becomes more readable

```
for f in Files:
    data = np.genfromtxt( f, delimiter = ';').T
    X.append( data[0] )
    Y.append( data[1] )
```

Comment: As I said "for each number corresponds only one file". I hope the confusion comes from the fact that the filename syntax was not showing the hash mark series '###". It was showing "_random_string.EXT' instead of '###_random_string.EXT'. I had to prepend a back slash to '###' to make it visible. I want numpy.genfromtxt to process only one file at a time.